# An array of Strings vs String Varargs

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

What is the difference between `void method(String[] a)` and `void method(String... a)`?

The first method take an array of Strings where as the second method takes one or more String arguments. What are the different features that they provide?

Moreover, don't know why but this is working:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"Hello", "World"};
        Test t = new Test();
        t.method(a);
    }

    void method(String...args) {
        System.out.println("Varargs");        // prints Varargs 
    }
}
```

Comment: Second one is just a *syntactic sugar* where you don't have to pass an array of a fixed size but a comma seperated value of Strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference, only if there are other elements after it in the signature.

For instance:

```
public void method(String[] args, String user){}
```

is possible, since there is no way the jvm will think `user` is still an element of `args`.

```
public void method(String ... args, String user){}
```

will cause trouble, though.

Comment: Just so you know: The bottom example doesn't even compile, java only allows varargs as the last parameter

Comment: String ... args should be the last argument. as public void method(String user, String ... args){}

Comment: @Ferrybig which is what I meant with "will cause trouble, though" and "only if there are other elements after it in the signature"

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is when you invoke the method, and the possible ways to invoke it as varargs allow multiple strings separated by "," or the use of an array as a parameter.

Important Note:

> varargs feature automates and hides the process of multiple args
>   passed in an array.

[Documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)

Edit:
Java doesn't allow this `public void method(String ... args, String user)`
as `varargs` must be the last parameter to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Not nice, but sometimes very usefull:
If at time of writing your code you do not know which args your method gets as input your code would look like

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Test t = new Test();
    String[] a = {"Hello", "World"};
    Integer [] b = {1,2};
    t.method(a);
    t.method(b);
    t.method('a',1,"String",2.3); 
}
void method(Object...args) {
    for (Object arg : args){
    System.out.println(arg);        
    }        
}
```